# How can i read only certain line from txt file in c?

Tags: c, file, scanf, line, fgets

I have this file and i Want to save in variables only the lines that dont start with //:

```
// Dimensoes da janela em termo de bolhas (largura e altura)
60 40
// Dimensão da bolha em pixeis (raio)
5
// dl – distancia para avaliação da colisão (percentagem do diametro)
0.95
// Numero de linhas inicias com bolhas
6
// Geração de uma nova linha de bolhas ao fim de N jogadas
10
```

Im not sure how i can do it. I've tryed with fscanf and fgets but im not doing it right
thanks in advance

Comment: Read each line and if it doesn't start with `//` keep it.

Comment: should i use fgets and save into a string?

Comment: Yes, use `fgets()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like:

```
FILE * inputFile; 
char str[256];
inputFile = fopen("fileName.txt", "r");
while(fgets(str, 256, inputFile) != NULL) {
    if (str[0] == '/' && str[1] == '/') {
        // Save string here
    }
}
```